# Ryzen 3 2200g vga port issue

Tags: vga, amd-ryzen

Today I bought 2200g computer. When I connected it to monitor only have vga port it didn't show anything. Later I try it with another   monitor with vga port face the same issue. Then I used another monitor with dvi input using hdmi to dvi cable it worked perfectly.
My question is problem is in apu or motherboard or bios? How do I fix this

Configuration
AMD RYZEN 3 2200G

GIGABYTE A320M S2H

ADATA 8GB DDR4 2400

TOSHIBA 1TB SATA3

DELUXE DW605

FSP 200W

ASUS DVDRW

LOGITECH MK120

Comment: Are the monitors known good monitors? Can you test the monitors on another computer? Are the cables known good cables? It could be that the port is not working on the motherboard. I don't think it would be the APU since it can display over the DVI interface.

Comment: One is aoc monitor and other one was Samsung monitor. Both monitors were currently using in the office

Comment: Sounds like just your DVI port is providing a display and not the VGA. Check in your bios for the video settings and see if VGA is disabled